# Remove trailing .html for 301 Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Trying to setup a redirect of a single subdirectory to a new subdomain.

I've setup as follows

```
Redirect 301 /ja/sales/ http://sales.domain.com
```

Old search results and links within the /ja/sales directory keep the page name redirecting to something like this: http://sales.domain.comabout.html

How do I fix this to redirect without the pagename and filetype?

Running Apache and using .htaccess in the root directory to do this. Should I instead do a catchall redirect in the directory in question with separate .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use `RedirectMatch` for support of regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ja/sales/ http://sales.domain.com/
```